# is there a way to get python to print out one of the variables by score

Tags: python

I am doing a food chooser in python. the user will answer questions based on the list printed out. what i am trying to figure is how to print a  single variable from the list based on the score from the question?

```
    food = ['donuts', 'pancakes', 'bacon', 'waffles', 'eggs', 'bagels']
    score = [0,0,0,0,0,0]
    
    print('Please answer each question with "y" for "yes" and "n" for "no".')
    user_input = input('Do you like food with holes? ')
    user_input2= input('do you like stuff made from animals? ')
    user_input3=input('do you like sweets')
    if user_input == 'y':
      score[0] = score[0] + 1
      score[5] = score[5] + 1
    else: user_input ='n'
    score[0] = score[0]-1
    score[1] = score[1]-1
    if user_input2 == 'y':
      score[0] = score[0] + 1
      score[5] = score[5] + 1
    else: user_input ='n'
    score[0] = score[0]-1
    score[1] = score[1]-1
    if user_input == 'y':
      score[0] = score[0] + 1
      score[5] = score[5] + 1
    else: user_input3 ='n'
    score[0] = score[0]-1
    score[1] = score[1]-1
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  I would believe that you'd loop through the ```score``` variable and find out which of the entries(if any) have the highest scores and then print them out.

Comment: thank you @ewong  how do i loop the score  because i am learning python still

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```py
print(score[i])
```

at the end if you are on version python3 where `i` is the index of the array